# How to transfer files to a usb mount with electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In an electron app I'm trying to transfer some files in an attached usb device.

I used usb-detection module to detect a new usb but it doesn't give any details about the mount path so how can I transfer files?

(Preferably cross platform solution)

Comment: [`usb`](https://github.com/tessel/node-usb) module seems to fit your needs

Comment: usb module doesn't give us the mount path. That's the main issue.

Comment: I've just seen this function: [`transfer`](https://github.com/tessel/node-usb#transferdata-callbackerror) which I guess can transfer files to the drive, but I'm not sure, never used it.

Comment: transfer seems to be doing very low level packet transfer. I was hoping they can provide a mount point which I can then use along with "fs" module to send files.

Comment: check the `usb` npm package

Comment: usb module doesn't give mount path information

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/drivelist : drivelist gives you the mount point as well, and supports all major OSes

Comment: drivelist is perfect :) Thanks . Please add an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

First you can use `os.platform()` to define the OS with file system. Then [nodejs exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) to spawn a process to be able to execute bash code to actually get the list of drives. Then simply return those values and use in the code with `fs`. Checkout in the example [here](https://github.com/shaun-h/nodejs-disks/blob/master/lib/disks.js#L15).

Comment: I'm going with drivelist but yes this is also one approach. Thanks